# Change http port for "Default Web Site"

Tags: c#, iis-7

I am using Microsoft.Web.Adminsitration assembly to create Application pool and website.

Refering to:

> [Microsoft.Web.Administration in IIS 7](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/carlosag/archive/2006/04/17/microsoftwebadministration.aspx)

This custom website should have port 80 for http communication. Since "Default Web Site" also uses port 80 by default, I need to programatically change this to another port (say 90). Is there a way of doing this programatically?

Answer (score 3):

Here's a sample snippet of code to change the existing port 80 http binding on the Default Web site to port 90:

```
int iisNumber = 1; // Default Website is IIS#1
using(ServerManager serverManager = new ServerManager())
{
  Site site = serverManager.Sites.FirstOrDefault(s => s.Id == iisNumber);
  if(site != null)
  {
    Binding binding = site.Bindings
        .Where(b => b.BindingInformation == "*:80:" && b.Protocol == "http")
        .FirstOrDefault();

    binding.BindingInformation = "*:90:";

    serverManager.CommitChanges();
    Console.WriteLine("");
  }
}
```

A `BindingInformation` field is a string comprised of:

`<ip address>:<port>:<host header>`

For example:

- `*:80:` - listen on all ip addresses, port 80, no host header
- `*:90:example.com` - listen on all ip addresses, port 80 but respond if the host header matches `example.com`
- `172.16.3.1:80:example.com` - listen on ip address 172.16.3.1, port 80 and if host header is `example.com`

Answer (score 0):

The  second line up "Creating a Site" in the blog post you mentioned  shows you how ...

```
iisManager.Sites.Add("NewSite", "http", "*:8080:", "d:\\MySite");
```

The parameter `*:8080` says the website should listen on all IP address bound to the machine on **Port 8080**.  Just change 8080 to the port you want.

FYI, 8080 is a traditional "off port" location for web sites.  Just keep in mind that you won't want to conflict with other services that are using ports.  You can see a list of reserved/registered ports here :http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_TCP_and_UDP_port_numbers

Comment: I think the OP wants to take port 80 for himself.