# Set website port with ServerManager class

Tags: c#, iis-7

I need help setting a port for a website using the Microsoft.Web.Administration.ServerManager class.

First I get the website:

```
Site site = this._serverManager.Sites[section.WebsiteName];
```

Then I try to set the port from my settings I passed in:

```
foreach (Binding b in from binding in site.Bindings.Where(b => b != null && b.EndPoint != null)
                                  select binding)
            {
                b.EndPoint.Port = Int32.Parse(section.Port);
                Console.WriteLine(b.EndPoint.Port);
            }    this._serverManager.CommitChanges();
```

I put the writeline in there to check and the port never gets changed why? I already know the website is valid because I check that before I get here.

```
Binding binding = site.Bindings.CreateElement();
                binding.BindingInformation = String.Format("{2}:{0}:{1}", section.Port,b.Host, b.EndPoint.Address);
                //b.EndPoint.Port = Int32.Parse(section.Port);
                site.Bindings.Add(binding);
```

I tried that above and I get a COMException about GetAttributeValue.

Finally got it thanks to the answer below I had to do:

```
b.BindingInformation = String.Format("{2}:{0}:{1}", section.Port, b.Host, b.EndPoint.Address);
```

Comment: A similar question with more information is available [on stackoverflow itself][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6101712/change-http-port-for-default-web-site#

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do you commit your changes?

This is the code I have in my server management app (created from data in a Xml document):

```
ServerManager manager = new ServerManager();
Site site = manager.Sites[siteName];

foreach (XElement bindingNode in bindingsNode.Elements("Binding")) {
    Binding binding = site.Bindings.CreateElement();
    binding.BindingInformation = String.Format("{2}:{0}:{1}", bindingNode.Attribute("Port").Value, bindingNode.Value, bindingNode.Attribute("IP").Value);
    site.Bindings.Add(binding);
}

manager.CommitChanges();
```

Comment: Have you tried my way of doing it? By setting the BindingInformation? "127.0.0.1:8080:domain.com" ?

Comment: Yes, and I get a COMException.

Comment: Okay, then it has to be something else that's the problem. What versions are you working with? IIS and .NET ?

Comment: IIS 7 and .NET4 not the client profile either and I am running as a 64 bit app.

Comment: Sorry, no idea then! Then only one left is permissions, "run as admin" ? Other than that, no idea!

Comment: Do I have to call stop on the site first?

Comment: Stopping didn't work either. Thank you for your help I'll keep working on it.

Comment: You were right I had to use the binding information. The exceptions was my fault because I just needed to change my current elements BindingInformation instead of creating anew one and adding it. Thank you for your help.