# How can I get the port by websites name via C# from IIS?

Tags: c#, web, port, servermanager

In IIS-Manager, the default web site is bound on port 80. How can I get the port by website-name, using c#? I tried the following code:

```
var lWebsite = "Default Web Site";
var lServerManager = new ServerManager();
var lPort = lServerManager.Sites[lWebsite].Bindings.GetAttributeValue("Port");
```

`lPort` results in null with an `invalid index` exception. But the assignment var `lPort = lServerManager.Sites[lWebsite]` works.

Comment: Please check the below link.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11616606/set-website-port-with-servermanager-class

Comment: One more link in msdn forum. http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/4d340847-25aa-47ee-aa43-b52c0565bfad/to-read-the-iis-default-website-port-number-c?forum=netfxbcl

Comment: @Jayesh Goyani: bindingNode.Attribute("Port").Value does also not work.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

When you access Sites[lWebsite].Bindings, you're accessing a *collection* of bindings. When you then try to call GetAttributeValue("Port"), it fails because that makes no sense - the collection itself doesn't have a port number associated with it, it's just a collection.

If you want to get access to the port number used by each binding, you need to loop through those bindings and ask each one for its associated port number:

```
var site = lServerManager.Sites[lWebsite];
foreach (var binding in site.Bindings)
{
    int port = binding.EndPoint.Port;
    // Now you have this binding's port, and can do whatever you want with it.
}
```

It's worth highlighting the fact that websites can be bound to multiple ports. You talk about getting "the" port, but that's not necessarily the case - for example, a website that's served over both HTTP and HTTPS will have two bindings, usually on ports 80 and 443. That's why you're having to deal with a *collection* of bindings, even though in your case that collection may only contain one binding it's still a collection.

For further details, have a look at the MSDN documentation for [the Binding class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.web.administration.binding%28v=vs.90%29.aspx). Note that some of what you're likely to be interested in will involve accessing the binding's EndPoint property, as in the sample above.